# Webpack bundle file shows lengthy references for import functions

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-5

I have a function `checkName` in my source code at `main/utils/name.js` file. And imported `checkName` in another file like below.

`import {checkName} from 'main/utils/name.js';`

When I try to debug my code in chrome devtool, in the final output bundle file, I see the reference to `checkName` function would be like - `_main_utils_name__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.checkName`. This is making my file look annoying while debugging in development phase of my project.

How to avoid these lengthy references for all the function names that are imported in any of the files in `Development Mode`?

Comment: You have to turn on source maps

Comment: Yes. I am using `'devtool': 'source-map'`. I tried all options for `devtool`. This is still not resolved.